# Why tilde (~) operator used with a constant RHS in R?

Tags: r, regression

I am wondering what does tilde (~) operator do in R when the right hand side is 1. This question was asked here [tilde(~) operator in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812741/tilde-operator-in-r)
However the answer is not satisfactory because it does not explain why one should use such a statement. This is because

```
> X~ 1
```

According to the above means that X is a constant variable but I am not sure why this should be used in a formula. Can anyone tell me how to interpret the above statement and when should I use such a statement? Does it mean that X should be interpreted as a constant number, this is because I have seen in some packages in R people model the dependent variable as like `response=X~1` and I do not understand what that means.

Comment: The `1` in `X ~ 1` denotes a constant offset, i.e. a parameter that is constant and not dependent on an independent variable. In the language of linear models, `y ~ 1` would note a model `y = beta0`; compare this to `y ~ x1` which translates to `y = beta0 + beta1 * x1`. We can also avoid a constant offset by specifying e.g. `y ~ 0 + x1` (or `y ~ x1 - 1`) which means `y = beta1 * x1`. It might be useful to take a look at `?formula` and `?offset`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks. However assume the response variable is Y=[1 10 0.8 12 0.5 24 2 5]. In this case still response=Y~1 is used inside the formula for a lot of examples in the R. This clearly does not make since it is saying that Y is a constant while according to my data this cannot be true.

Comment: In `lm(y ~ 1)` you are *fitting* a model (using OLS) and in doing so are estimating a constant offset parameter; this corresponds to estimating the overall mean of your measurements `y_i`. I'm not sure how this is not clear. The `formula` syntax might be a bit idiosyncratic but it makes a lot of sense IMO once you wrap your head around it.

Comment: To make it even clearer, run `lm(Y ~ 1);mean(Y)`.

Comment: The model doesn't say the *value* of Y is constant. A regression model is a model for the conditional expectation. That model says that the mean of all the Y's is the same. If you give that to `lm` to estimate, it estimates that common population mean for you (by using the sample mean, which is the least squares fit).

Answer (score 1):

Formulas do not have independent meaning in R.  Each function which accepts a formula can interpret them in any way it likes.  for example, `plot(0, main = X ~ 1)` interprets tilde as a space.

If you are referring to how `lm` (and many other modelling functions) interpret formulas then `X ~ 1` means regress the vector `X` onto an intercept only model or stated otherwise it means regress `X` onto the vector consisting of all ones.  The `model.matrix` function shows the right hand side that is implied by the model formula.

```
# test data
X <- 1:4

# run regression
fm <- lm(X ~ 1)

# compute model matrix representing right hand side
m <- model.matrix(fm)
m
##   (Intercept)
## 1           1
## 2           1
## 3           1
## 4           1
## attr(,"assign")
## [1] 0
```

As an example of using this:

```
coef(fm)
## (Intercept) 
##         2.5

# perform same computation directly using model matrix, m, and X
solve(t(m) %*% m) %*% t(m) %*% X
##             [,1]
## (Intercept)  2.5
```

Comment: while it's true that any function can interpret a formula however it wants, many (most?) functions that use formulas in a statistical context (including `lm()`) pass the formula to `model.matrix()`, so this answer is much more broadly applicable than it initially seems